# Need to place string in file in specific place

Tags: string, replace, sh, cpu-word

Goal is to take string from one file and replace the specific string in another file.

Almost done, but need to know the marked line, or maybe there is more relevant solution.
Thanks.

```
if grep -q "edem_pl" /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini ; then
        grep edem_pl /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini > /sdcard/temp.txt
        else
        echo "no edemtv user"
        fi 

    **********************
    after making some actions
    **********************

    if [ -e "/sdcard/temp.txt" ]; then
    **copy string from /sdcard/temp.txt and replace with it string that contains edemtv in /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini**
    else
    echo "no edemtv user"
    fi
```

Comment: You should tag this with [tag:sh]. Also... which string? Where do you put it in the other file?

Comment: Replace the string which contains word edemtv

Comment: Do you mean to replace the string that's on the same line in the other file?

Comment: the difficulty is that its NOT on the same line

Comment: Could you provide some sample files? I have absolutely no clue what you're asking.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n3Qd71h3

Comment: copy whole line 40 if exists and place it in some tmp file

Comment: and after making some actions

Comment: Oh... You can use `grep` to get just those lines and then use `>>` to redirect them into a file. If you get it working, please post an answer.

Comment: copy contents of tmp file and replace the string which contains edemtv, such as line 7 in second example

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MqREUHiB

Comment: if [ -e "/sdcard/temp.txt" ]; then
sed 's/edemtv/edem_pl/g' /sdcard/temp.txt >> /sdcard/DiseqTree2.ini

Comment: this command works, but it only appends a line in file, not replacing

Comment: Don't link to external sources, make your question self-contained; see [mcve].

Comment: still no solution

Comment: @user3774027 I understand what you want now! I'll (suggest an) edit (to) your question, then answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
sed s/edem_pl/edemtv/g
```

will act as a filter that replaces (`s`ubstitutes) all lines (`g`lobally) containing `edem_pl` that are passed through it with equivalent lines containing `edemtv` instead. You can insert this into your command like so:

```
grep edem_pl /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini | sed s/edem_pl/edemtv/g > /sdcard/temp.txt
```

and `/sdcard/temp.txt` will contain only the lines originally containing `edem_pl`, with `edemtv` substituted for them.

---

Keep in mind that `edem_pl` and `edemtv` are being treated as regular expressions here. In this case, no special escaping needs to be done, but if they contain regex special characters like `[` and `^` those characters will need to be escaped with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution

```
sed -i "s!.*edemtv.*!$(cat /sdcard/temp.txt)!g" /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini
```

also

```
replace=`grep edem_pl /sdcard/temp.txt`
sed -i "s/.*edemtv.*/$replace/g" /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini
```

one more

```
busybox sed -i '/.*edemtv.*/{
    r /sdcard/temp.txt
    d
    }' /sdcard/DiseqTree.ini
```

thanks to 4pda community